# Terracotta error: Assertion failed: No space in buffers to read more data

Tags: java, terracotta

I'm getting the error listed below from Terracotta.  I'm a total newbie with TC.  Can someone point me in the right direction as to what I need to do to fix this?

```
2016-03-22 15:38:51,531 default [Terracotta] INFO boot.ProcessExecuter - java.lang.RuntimeException: com.tc.util.TCAssertionError: Assertion failed: No space in buffers to read more data
```

UPDATE.

**version**: terracotta 3.6.2

**configuration**...the config file is pretty long

**usage**: see "total newbie" from above.  I'm not really sure what purpose terracotta serves

```
 default [Terracotta] INFO boot.ProcessExecuter - java.lang.RuntimeException: com.tc.util.TCAssertionError: Assertion failed: No space in buffers to read more data
 default [Terracotta] INFO boot.ProcessExecuter -   at com.tc.net.core.CoreNIOServices$CommThread.run(CoreNIOServices.java:293)
 default [Terracotta] INFO boot.ProcessExecuter - Caused by: com.tc.util.TCAssertionError: Assertion failed: No space in buffers to read more data
 default [Terracotta] INFO boot.ProcessExecuter -   at com.tc.util.Assert.failure(Assert.java:60)
 default [Terracotta] INFO boot.ProcessExecuter -   at com.tc.util.Assert.eval(Assert.java:80)
 default [Terracotta] INFO boot.ProcessExecuter -   at com.tc.util.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:100)
 default [Terracotta] INFO boot.ProcessExecuter -   at com.tc.net.protocol.AbstractTCProtocolAdaptor.getReadBuffers(AbstractTCProtocolAdaptor.java:61)
 default [Terracotta] INFO boot.ProcessExecuter -   at com.tc.net.protocol.ProtocolSwitch.getReadBuffers(ProtocolSwitch.java:133)
 default [Terracotta] INFO boot.ProcessExecuter -   at com.tc.net.core.TCConnectionImpl.getReadBuffers(TCConnectionImpl.java:794)
 default [Terracotta] INFO boot.ProcessExecuter -   at com.tc.net.core.TCConnectionImpl.doReadFromBufferInternal(TCConnectionImpl.java:433)
 default [Terracotta] INFO boot.ProcessExecuter -   at com.tc.net.core.TCConnectionImpl.doReadFromBuffer(TCConnectionImpl.java:306)
 default [Terracotta] INFO boot.ProcessExecuter -   at com.tc.net.core.TCConnectionImpl.doReadInternal(TCConnectionImpl.java:290)
 default [Terracotta] INFO boot.ProcessExecuter -   at com.tc.net.core.TCConnectionImpl.doRead(TCConnectionImpl.java:266)
 default [Terracotta] INFO boot.ProcessExecuter -   at com.tc.net.core.CoreNIOServices$CommThread.selectLoop(CoreNIOServices.java:624)
 default [Terracotta] INFO boot.ProcessExecuter -   at com.tc.net.core.CoreNIOServices$CommThread.run(CoreNIOServices.java:290)
```

Comment: Would be good to have information around your setup: version, configuration, usage scenario, ...

Comment: Well, I would suggest going for the documentation then and doing a few tests with a more recent version as well. Latest open source version is 4.3.1. And changes from 3.6.2 are pretty big.